# Weblogic 10.3.5: <prefer-web-inf-classes> in weblogic.xml not working VS. server classpath JAR files

Tags: jsf-2, weblogic, mojarra

**Weblogic version**: 10.3.5

**JSF version (interfaces, impl) :** Mojarra 2.0.3

I have a JSF `EAR` application which is made up of a `WAR` file and a `JAR` file.

The `WAR` file contains the following two `Maven` dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

When running, the following code snippet **correctly** reports the current in-service version of `Mojarra` as v2.0.3:

```
public void getMojarraVersion() {
    Package p = FacesContext.class.getPackage();
    System.out.println("Mojarra version: " + p.getImplementationTitle() + " " + p.getImplementationVersion());
}
```

The weblogic startup log, however reports that a different, far older version provided by the container, is used when the application is started:

```
INFO: Initializing Sun's JavaServer Faces implementation (1.2_03-b04-FCS) for context '/myApp'
```

This is despite the following `weblogic.xml` configuration, deployed alongside the `WAR` file's `web.xml` file in `WEB-INF`, which inverts the classloader:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
     <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
     </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

After a couple of days of digging, I discovered the following two JAR Files are being included in the server classpath:

```
${WEBLOGIC_HOME}/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/consoleapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-api.jar

${WEBLOGIC_HOME}/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/consoleapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl.jar
```

These files are provided by a vanilla install of `Weblogic` 10.3.5.

Temporarily removing these two JAR files and restarting the server caused the log to start reporting that the new version is in use:

```
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.3 for context '/myApp'
```

The above evidence therefore demonstrates that Weblogic configuration to subvert the classloader hierarchy **does not work** for any resources that are provided by the server classpath (i.e. `${WEBLOGIC_HOME}/wlserver_10.3/server/lib`) when an application is loaded.

As an interesting aside, I can delete the `weblogic.xml` file and I find that:

1. The wrong version of the dependency continues to be reported in the startup log.
2. The correct version of the dependency continues to be used at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Sometime `<wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>` can't specify the lib. You need to use: `<wls:prefer-application-packages>` and `<wls:prefer-application-resources>`. Below is an example (remove wls: for old weblogic version):

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.google.common.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.logging.log4j.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:prefer-application-resources>
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>com.google.common.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>org.apache.logging.log4j.*</wls:resource-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-resources>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

On top of weblogic.xml use this:
`<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.2/weblogic-web-app.xsd">`

Comment: Yes. I found today that <prefer-application-resources> can be a blunt tool, while <prefer-application-*> is the surgeon's scalpel. BTW, I only needed one schema: 
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">

Answer (score 2):

The prefer-web-inf-classes setting only applies to the web application level.
I can't tell from the output provided, but it looks like the classloader for your ear is loading the other jar files.  The classloader for your war will load and use the newer jar based on your setting, even though the root application loaded the others.

If you want to see this happen at the ear level, you can add a classloader filter.  WebLogic 12c allows this at both the war and ear level: [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/configurejsfandjtsl.htm)

I've only read about 10.3.5 allowing the filter at the ear level: [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13706/app_xml.htm#r25c1-t2)

Comment: Hi @beaston, the problem is that, at runtime within the app I can prove that the new `JAR` is being used, however when Weblogic starts the application it uses the version of the `JAR` on its own `classpath`. I have experimented with a classloader filter & this has not fixed the problem. The only way I have managed to override a jar in `system/lib` is to forcibly remove it from the directory. Sadly for me this is not an option in our Production environment. I am disheartened that this site & others like it are litered with questions lamenting how this feature doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

8bitjunkie- Hi. I believe that your third party jar files are included to your EAR by the framework and the in-built listener/classes addition logic used in your application or in your application's third party libraries. The framework may be spring in your case.
If this is the case, then either,

1. You need to modify the main application's configuration before creating the EAR in such a way that the third party library's dependency be removed. for eg: in Ivy.xml, used  for all the dependencies that downloads this 'jsf-impl' jar.
2. You need to modify the main application's code logic to implement either servletcontextlistener class or servletcontainerInitializer class based on the context i.e., former must be used if your classes form a part integral to your own web application and letter must be used if jar is packaged to WAR which in turn bundled into EAR and deployed in server as EAR application. Hope this helps